# Codeigniter-4 Update query issue Not setting the fields i want to set

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

In my User controller i try to update my remember_token field but update query not working as i want 
in my UserModel i have my 
 protected $allowedFields = ['username', 'email','password','email_verified_at','remember_token'] 
it contain remember_token the controller code is below

```
$User = new UserModel();
$userdata = $User->where('email', $this->request->getPost('email'))->first();
if($this->request->getPost('remember')){
    $token = random_string('md5', 32);
    set_cookie('remembermetoken', $token,'3600'); 
                //   issue not solved with update
                     $newdata=['remember_token'=>$token];
                     $User->update($userdata['id'],$newdata);
                // the above line of code produce 
                //UPDATE `user` SET = '' WHERE `user`.`id` IN ('5')
                // why it is not setting remember_token
                //contrary to that if i use 
                //$User->query("UPDATE `user` SET `remember_token`='".$token."' WHERE `id`='".$userdata['id']."'");
                // it will produce correct query ?   
                //UPDATE `user` SET `remember_token`='d0dc17846d297bb28ac37e16e280060d' WHERE `id`= '5'
```

pleas help me with this Codeigniter-4 issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: Does it work with the alternative query builder syntax like `$User->where('id', $userdata['id'])->set($newdata)->update();`?

Comment: thanks for the response but still not working with $User->where('id', $userdata['id'])->set($newdata)->update(); producing  this UPDATE `user` SET = '' WHERE `id` = '5'

Comment: It is solved i have UserModel whre i have call back of beforeUpdate operation where i was just hashing the password and returning only password and nothing else Now done Thanks Every One for your concerns

Comment: Sorry I missed your earlier reply. Glad to hear you solved it!